# Email method not working

Tags: java, search, hashmap

Hey i have an EmployeeStore which i have used a hashmap for this.  The variables that the map stores are email name and id.  I have a method called SearchByEmail but there is a problem with this.  The method returns false when the user inputs a correct employee email into the UI.

Here is my code:
This is in the MainApp

```
 case 2:
               System.out.println("Search by Email.");
               Employee employeeSearchEmail = MenuMethods.userInputByEmail();
                 Store.searchByEmail(employeeSearchEmail.getEmployeeEmail());
```

MenuMethods

```
//Imports
import java.util.Scanner;
//********************************************************************

public class MenuMethods 
{
    private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);



    //Methods for the Company Application menu.
    //Method for validating the choice.
         public static int getMenuChoice(String menuString, int limit, String prompt, String errorMessage) 
         {
                System.out.println(menuString);
                int choice = inputAndValidateInt(1, limit, prompt, errorMessage);
                return choice;
         }
    //********************************************************************
    //This method is used in the getMenuChoice method.
            public static int inputAndValidateInt(int min, int max, String prompt, String errorMessage) 
            {
                int number;
                boolean valid;
                do {
                    System.out.print(prompt);
                    number = keyboard.nextInt();
                    valid = number <= max && number >= min;
                    if (!valid) {
                        System.out.println(errorMessage);
                    }
                } while (!valid);
                return number;
            }
    //********************************************************************
    public static Employee userInput()
    {
         String temp = keyboard.nextLine();
         Employee e = null;
         System.out.println("Please enter the Employee Name:");
         String employeeName = keyboard.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Please enter the Employee ID:");
         int employeeId = keyboard.nextInt();
         temp = keyboard.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Please enter the Employee E-mail address:");
         String employeeEmail  = keyboard.nextLine();
         return e = new Employee(employeeName , employeeId, employeeEmail);

    }
    //********************************************************************
    public static Employee userInputByName()
    {
        //String temp is for some reason needed.  If it is not included
        //The code will not execute properly.
         String temp = keyboard.nextLine();
         Employee e = null;
         System.out.println("Please enter the Employee Name:");
         String employeeName = keyboard.nextLine();

         return e = new Employee(employeeName);

    }
    //********************************************************************
    public static Employee userInputByEmail()
    {
        //String temp is for some reason needed.  If it is not included
        //The code will not execute properly.
         String temp = keyboard.nextLine();
         Employee e = null;
         System.out.println("Please enter the Employee Email:");
         String employeeEmail = keyboard.nextLine();
        //This can use the employeeName's constructor because java accepts the parameters instead
         //of the name's.
         return e = new Employee(employeeEmail);

    }
    //********************************************************************


}
```

SearchByEmail

```
public boolean searchByEmail(String employeeEmail) 
    {
            //(for(Employee e : map.values()) {...}) 
            //and check for each employee if his/her email matches the searched value
            boolean employee = map.equals(employeeEmail);    
            System.out.println(employee);
            return employee;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,

```
map.equals(employeeEmail);
```

doesn't really make sense. `map` is a `Hashmap`, and `employeeEmail` is a `String`. Under what conditions would they be equal?

It is unclear what you store in the map and how, since you have neither included the declaration of the map, nor the code that inserts new values. I'll assume for now that you store mappings like `name -> Employee`. If you want to search for an employee based on an email address I suggest you do something like

```
Employee findByEmail(String email) {
    for (Employee employee : yourMap.values())
        if (employee.getEmail().equals(email))
            return employee;

    // Not found.
    return null;
}
```

then to check if an employee with `email` exists, you could do

```
public boolean searchByEmail(String employeeEmail) {
    boolean employee = findByEmail(employeeEmail) != null;
    System.out.println(employee);
    return employee;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume map is of type `Map<S,T>` for some S,T, and thus it is not of the same type as `employeeEmail`, and specifically it does not `equals()` it.

I suspect you are looking for [`Map.containsValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsValue%28java.lang.Object%29) (if the email is the value in the map) or [`Map.containsKey()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29) (if the email is the key of the map), depending on what exactly `map` is mapping, if the mapping is to/from the string value.

**EDIT:** based on clarifications on comments:

Since the email is not a key nor value in `map`, the suggested solution won't work as it is. So you can chose one of those:

1. Use @aioobe's solution to iterate and check each email.
2. Add an extra field to the class: `Map<String,Employee> map2` which will map: `email_address->employee`. Given this map, you can search for an email using `map2.containsKey(email)`. It will ensure faster lookup for an employee from an email and the expanse of holding an extra map. I'd go with this choice if I were you.

Comment: `Map.containsValue` may be problematic to use if all you know is the email-address.

Comment: You are correct in assuming the maps type.  I also did try your suggestion but i got no joy :( The output still returns false.

Comment: @Pendo826: What is the *type* of `map` exactly? what is it mapping?

Comment: @aioobe: It of course depends on the exact type which is being mapped, if the email address is a key/value in it - it is probably the best solution. If it is not - then it might be wise to keep an extra `Map<String,T>` if this operation happens a lot.

Comment: @amit The map is String,Employee.

Comment: @Pendo826: And is the `String` the email address? If it is, you are looking for the `containsKey()` method.

Comment: no name is the key.  I take email in through the employee class.

Comment: @Pendo826: Then this solution won't work, you might use aioobe's suggestion OR add an extra map `Map<String,Employee> map2` which will map from email address to the employee, and use `map2.containsKey(email)`. It will make a look up for an employee's email much faster!